# zlib compression for wiredTiger engine in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, zlib, wiredtiger

Mongod is not starting when I include the zlib options for wiredTiger engine. When I disable it, It works just fine. I updated the options in the mongod.conf file and used service mongod start to initiate the database. It gives me the following error : "Job for mongod.service failed. See 'systemctl status mongod.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details". Can anyone who has previously used the zlib compression in Mongo 3.0 let me know what is going on ? I think it may be the syntax related to zlib in the config file.

Comment: Well, with my magical superpowers I can analyze the log remotely (without even knowing the hostname, because just from your name I can read your mind, too) and come to the conclusion that you made a mistake. ;) Please add the config file and the according excerpt of the log file for the non-superpowered (although most of us are). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the MongoDB from command line, without the systemctl or init.d script, it might print the error message to the standard out or err.

I got this error when I had MongoDB configuration file in the old format and then had added configuration options on new format there. Generally, if there is anything on the config file MongoDB does not recognize, it fails to start and usually you get that message.